# Get max count from laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model **Topic** which has hasMany relationship with **Game** model.

```
 //Topic.php

 public function Games() {
    return $this->hasMany(Game::class);
}


 //Game.php

 public function Topic() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class);
}
```

What I need is getting the Topic which has the max count (also the count value) of Games based on 'created_at' today,this week,this month etc. I tried the following code, but the nested whereBetween query does not work, instead it is showing all the related topic->games created ever

```
 $top_topic_month = Topic::with('games')->get()->sortBy(function($q)
                  {
                            return $q->games->whereBetween('created_at',[today()->startOfMonth, today()])->count();
                  })->first();

 $top_topic_month_count = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

use `withCount` to generate `games_count`

```php
$top_topic_month = Topic::withCount('games')->whereHas('games',function($q) use($startMonth){
        $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$startMonth, today()]);
    })->orderByDesc('games_count')->first();

 $top_topic_month_count = $top_topic_month->count()
```

Comment: Thanks! all I needed to use a get() before the max('games_count') to make it work. As I needed the topic instance along with the max value, I used orderBy('games_count')

Thanks for helping me reaching out almost to the end

Comment: Your welcome if it is solved your problem mark this answer so other can take benefit  thank you